# Rails doesn't allow me to set 'date' field to more than 30 days in advance - Help - Rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

On my `User` model, I have an attribute `trial_end_date`.

The column in the table looks like this:

```
#  trial_end_date       :date
```

However, if I try to change the date to far in the future, at the Rails console, this is what happens:

```
a = User.find(2)
a.trial_end_date = "2019-12-30"
=> "2019-12-30"
>> a.save
=> true
>> a.trial_end_date
=> Sat, 19 Nov 2011
```

WTF? Why does it do that? I have no idea why it does this?

Even if I try `update_attributes(:trial_end_date => "2019-12-30")` the same thing happens.

Here are all the methods in my `User` model that relate to `trial_end_date`:

```
after_validation :set_trial_end

   def has_trial_expired?
        if (self.trial_end_date <= Date.today)
            return true
        else
            return false
        end
    end

    def set_trial_end
      plan = self.plan
      end_of_trial = Date.today + self.plan.trial_duration.days
      self.trial_end_date = end_of_trial.to_date
    end

    def trial_will_almost_end?
        if (self.trial_end_date - Date.today <= 3)
            return true
        else
            return false
        end
    end

    def when_does_trial_end?
        self.trial_end_date
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

marcamillion,

You commented that you thought that you thought that validation would happen "just on the initial user creation."  As comments have pointed out, that's not true if you use after_validation, but it IS true if you use

```
before_validation_on_create
```

(See, for example, http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html )

Using that would restrict the *creation* of dates by your users, but wouldn't prevent you (or them! Be careful!) from changing them later in other ways.

Answer (score 2):

After validation the trial_end_date gets set based on the plan duration, no?

Comment: When does validation happen? I thought that was just on the initial user creation. Or does that happen every time a user object is modified?

Comment: You may be right...given that I need the `after_validation`, how can I modify this to allow me to manually override that `after_validation` call?

Comment: @marcamillion Not on modification, but on save, in this case. IIRC you can turn that off by passing :validate => false to save (could be wrong), but... do you *want* to bypass this business logic?

Comment: I only want to bypass it in some cases...e.g. only when I want to extend the trial via the console. I can't think of a business rule for X number of users right now...but there are times when I want to go in and extend the trial period for my users. I would like to have the option of doing more than 30 days if I need to - rather than being held hostage.

Comment: @marcamillion Okay; I'll let you figure all that domain-specific stuff out ;)

Answer (score 1):

One refinement to Bob's answer: *_on_create and its ilk are deprecated in 3.0 and removed in 3.1. In the interest of maintainability, you probably want to adopt the new form:

```
before_validation :some_method, :on => :create
```

It's a quick tweak that'll save you headaches in the future.